# calculate a field in mysql table

Tags: mysql

I am very new to MySQL and db's in general.

I have a table where I have `date_of_test` and `test_frequency` (Possible values 3,6,12).

I need to have a field `future_test` that has the calculated date in it derived from `date_of_test` and the value in `test_frequency` which is either 3,6,12 (Months).

I do not know how to achieve this, could somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: Don't store calculated fields in the database itself always just output them to the application. So the answer depends entirely on what you're outputting to and in what format the date is stored.

Comment: Posting your table structure and one or two rows would help a lot more.

Comment: Thank you for a very quick response.In this instance I need to store the calculated value in the db field as I am using another prog to display the data on the web. The date format is d-m-Y.

Comment: The table is called gypsum the fields are as described above. I dont as yet know how to post my table structure? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try [DATE_ADD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function in my sql

ex:

```
 SELECT '2008-12-31 23:59:59' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alter table gypsum add column future_test (datetime);

update gypsum
  set future_test = date_add(date_of_test, interval test_frequency MONTH);
```

As pointed in comments, it's often not a great idea to have calculated values in a database.

You'll have to relaunch the calculation each time you update a date_or_test, a test_frequency, or each time you insert a new value...

It might be better to create a dedicated view

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW gypsumWithFuture AS
(SELECT
  id, 
  date_of_test, 
  test_frequency, 
  DATE_ADD(date_of_test, interval test_frequency MONTH) AS future_test
 FROM gypsum)
```

or to do the calculation in your application's code (if you have one). A wide range of langagues has DateTime function, which can do the same as MySQL [DATE_ADD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).

Comment: Thank you gents for a very quick response. Can I use a trigger to update the table every time a record is added / updated?

Comment: @user1731603 this might be a solution,yes. But a view will always be "up-to-date".

Comment: The application I am using "Fabrikar for joomla" does not allow me to display data from a table and a view simultaneously that is why I am going down this route.